# Why imagemagick mogrify command not found and how to solve this?

Tags: bash, imagemagick, automator, mogrify

I'm trying to write automation service that gets all images exclude .jpg from the current directory (or selected files), convert them to .jpg by imagemagick mogrify and delete old images.

script: `mogrify -format jpg *.* && find . -type f  ! -name "*.jpg"  -delete`

I've tried my script in the terminal and it works fine.

Then, I've created automator service for doing the same thing from context menu and I'm stacked.

[image: automator script]

It make error

> The action “Run Shell Script” encountered an error: “zsh:1: command
> not found: mogrify”

UPD.

Thanks to Mark Setchell, `/opt/homebrew/bin/magick` works fine, but i'm still having errors that you can see below. Looks like the script executing in the incorrect folder.

[image]

UPD2.

I fixed it by passing input as argument and using this argument (folder) for changing directory before script

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are on a Mac, you probably installed via **homebrew**, so **ImageMagick** binaries are likely in `/usr/local/bin` or `/opt/somewhere`.

You can use this command in **Terminal** to find it:

```
find /opt /usr -name magick
```

So if you find `/opt/somewhere/bin/magick`, use:

```
/opt/somewhere/bin/magick mogrify ...
```

in your script.

---

Prior to v7, **ImageMagick** had lots of commands in its suite - `convert`, `mogrify`, `compare`, `compose`, `animate`, `conjure`, `display` and so on. In v7, all commands were prefixed with `magick` so there is just one command and *"the namespace is less polluted"* as some folks call it. The `convert` command also used to clash with some Microsoft `CONVERT.EXE` thing on Windows that converts filesystems from one format to another.

Comment: `/opt/homebrew/bin/magick` works, thank you! Unfortunately i got another error. Looks like it tried to convert inside incorrect folder.

The action “Run Shell Script” encountered an error: “mogrify: no decode delegate for this image format `LOCALIZED' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/741.
mogrify: no decode delegate for this image format `SH' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/741.

Comment: Try printing the name of the image. I guess you are trying to convert a file that isn't an image. *"Can't decode"* means it is an unreadable format.

Comment: You can use `magick mogrify -verbose ...` too.

Comment: I've updated the question. As you can see, there are only images

Comment: Your script is likely running in a different directory from where you think - it is reading JSON, PHP, shell and LOG files. Try printing the directory with `pwd`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to prepend 'magick' to the command. If you've added ImageMagick as an environment variable, that will suffice. If you have not, you need the path to the magick executable.

Comment: I've tried magick and got error too `The action “Run Shell Script” encountered an error: “zsh:1: command not found: magick`. How can i find the path to the magic executable?